# Fill column with random values with a set of given options (ENUM)

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

I have a MYSQL Table with 3 different columns:

- 'id': Primary key / autoincrement
- 'code': is null for now and will be filled by a script later
- 'rtcgroup': is of type ENUM and can only be either "Group A" or "Group B"

Now, I would like to add multiple rows by SQL code, in which the columns 'id' and 'code' are inserted with the default values (id->autoincrement & code->Null) and 'rtcgroup' should be filled randomly with either "Group A" or "Group B". I would like to be able to define the number of rows which will be added in that code. And the randomization of Group A or B should happen for every row

I have searched for a solution and came up with the usage of a CASE statement: My problem here is, that I don't know how to apply this statement to each row individually and it only worked for already preallocated empty rows. I am looking for a solution, where I can define in the code, how many rows should be added to the table.

```
UPDATE `rtc`
SET `rtcgroup`=(CASE floor(rand())
                WHEN 0 THEN 'Group A'
                WHEN 1 THEN 'Group B'
                END);
```

I also tried to implement the mentioned code into a procedure with following code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_loop_test()
BEGIN
    DECLARE int_val INT DEFAULT 0;
    test_loop : LOOP
    IF(int_val = 10) THEN
    LEAVE test_loop
    END IF;
    INSERT INTO `rtc`(`code`, `rtcgroup`) VALUES (NULL,     CASE floor(rand())
                WHEN 0 THEN 'Group A'
                WHEN 1 THEN 'Group B'
                END);
    SET int_val = int_val+1;
    END LOOP;
    END;
    CALL proc_loop_test;
```

This always creates following error message:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'test_loop : LOOP
    IF(int_val = 10) THEN
    LEAVE test_loop
    END IF' at line 4
```

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: You forget about `DELIMITER`.

Comment: Do not convert numbers to string values - you may assign numeric index into ENUM column.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by DELIMITER? I looked it up, but I haven't worked with it before. And the assiging of ENUM works with numeric values? So I can just assign e.g. 1 and it will insert 'Group A'?

Comment: *Could you explain what you mean by DELIMITER?* https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html *And the assiging of ENUM works with numeric values? So I can just assign e.g. 1 and it will insert 'Group A'?* https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html